# Ag Grid in Angular buttons Clear and Apply in filters aren't visible

Tags: angular, filter, ag-grid

I have ag grid with filters copied from example from angular web page:
[enter link description here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-provided/)

This is my code:

```
  <ag-grid-angular #agGrid
                   style="width: 100%; height: 200px;" class="ag-theme-mystyle"
                   id="myGrid"
              (gridReady)="onGridReady1($event)"
                   [columnDefs]="columnDefs1"
                   [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef1"
                   [rowData]="rowData1"
                    ></ag-grid-angular>
```

and in typescript:

```
this.columnDefs1 = [
      {
        field: 'athlete',
        filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
        filterParams: {
          buttons: ['reset', 'apply'],
        },
      },
..
}
this.defaultColDef1 = {
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 150,
      filter: true,
    };
```

And buttons Clear and Apply filter aren't shown:
[image]

Comment: have you tried to set " filter: true " instead of " filter: 'agTextColumnFilter' "?

Comment: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-provided-simple/, have a look at the Simple Filters docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your scenario. The only change i did was that class name of **ag-theme-alpine** instead of **ag-theme-mystyle** in your html file. Try this out, you will see your buttons.[image]